# Signature level(PAdES-B/T/LT/LTA) using PDFBox?

Tags: java, pdfbox, digital-signature, bouncycastle, pades

Is there any way I can display the signature level(PAdES B/T/LT/LTA) using PDFBox?
I checked the [`ShowSignature.java`](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/signature/ShowSignature.java?view=log) class, but I didn't find anything like that.

Comment: What exactly do you want displayed? Whether some formal criteria for those profiles are fulfilled or whether it is done good enough for validation use? E,g, for LT does it suffice for you to have a T plus an incremental update with some validation related information? Or do those information have to suffice to allow validation without retrieving additional information (except the trust lists)? There are quite a lot of tasks to execute for the latter option while the former one should be implementable as an example.

Comment: I'm looking for something like the second option

Comment: I'm afraid that's not implemented in the pdfbox distribution, and it also is far beyond the scope of a single stack overflow question.

Comment: Can you tell me what steps I should follow to verify a PAdES signature up to the LTA level? @mkl

Comment: That is specified in [ETSI EN 319 102-1](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_en/319100_319199/31910201/01.03.01_60/en_31910201v010301p.pdf) in section 5 "Signature validation" in combination with the PAdES specification [ETSI EN 319 142-1](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_en/319100_319199/31914201/01.01.01_60/en_31914201v010101p.pdf). Some extra details are ruled by the European Commission but simply following the two ETSI norms above should suffice in general.